# Check and uncheck a checkbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to create a function to check and uncheck checkboxes when we click on the previous span element, it works one time but it doesn't work a second time... I don't understand...

My html code :

```
<form class="form" action="#" method="post">
  <label>Input radio</label>
  <span>Text</span><input type="checkbox">
  <span>Text</span><input type="checkbox">
  <span>Text</span><input type="checkbox">
  <label>Input checkbox</label>
  <span>Text</span><input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span>Text</span><input type="radio" name="radio">
</form>
```

My js code :

```
$('form.form').find('span').on('click', function(){
    $this = $(this);
    if( $(this).next().attr('type') == 'checkbox' ){ 
        if( $this.next().is(':checked') ){
            $this.next().attr('checked', false);
        }else{
            $this.next().attr('checked', true);
        }
    }else{
        $this.next().attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

**Update 1**

URL : http://jsfiddle.net/tonymx227/bvPsq/

Anthony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use **[prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** for that

```
$this.next().prop('checked', false);
```

The reason it works the first time is because jQuery changes the attribute, and the checkbox is updated, but the `checked` property of the element is not updated, and that it was jQuery uses internally to see if the checkbox is checked, so the next time you try to change it, the attribute says it's checked, and the checkbox appears to be checked, but jQuery thinks it's not checked as that is what the property is saying, as it wasn't set with  `attr()`.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bvPsq/1/)

Answer (score 1):

This is where you can use a label, wrap your inputs with a label. You don't necessarily need to use Javascript for this.

```
<label>Text<input type="checkbox" /></label>
```

or you can use `label for` if you have check boxes with id associated with it.

```
<label for="chk1">Text</label> <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" />
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rwt5c/)**

> The HTML  Element represents a caption for an item in a user interface. It can be associated with a control either by using the for attribute, or by placing the control element inside the label element. Such a control is called the labeled control of the label element.

Comment: Yes I know that but I didn't want to use this method ;-) Thank you anyway !